# How to get a word's suffix after lemmatizing it (Python)?

Tags: python, lemmatization, suffix

I need to get the suffix of a word after lemmatizing it. I wonder if there is a way to "subtract" a lemma from a word and get the suffix as a result?
I've tried re.sub but of course it works only in certain cases, namely those in which the lemma is to be found in the word (thus it doesn't work with "dancing", "ladies" etc.). I don't know if there is a better way to do this.

```
word = "produced"
lemma = lemmatizer_.lemmatize(word, "v")
suffix = re.sub(lemma, "", word)
suffix
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, You may need to have a look on `Source code for nltk.stem.porter`  [link](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/stem/porter.html)

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to get rid of the suffix, but of the lemma. All these methods seem to only strip the word from its suffix.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
def get_suffix(word, lemma):
    cnt = sum(w==l for w, l in zip(word, lemma))
    return word[cnt:]
print('suffix:', get_suffix('dancing', 'dance'))
print('suffix:', get_suffix('ladies',  'lady'))

>> suffix: ing
>> suffix: ies
```

Obviously this won't work with irregular forms and there  are probably some other corner cases, but for the basic endings it looks like it will work.